# Serialize/Deserialize Tree to Json

Tags: c#, javascript, json, angularjs

I use .Net Framework with WebApi on my Server and Javascript/AngularJs on my Client. I want to transfer an Tree with References to my Client. I found a Way to get it to the Client, i just set PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects at the Newtonsoft Json.

Json looks like this:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "id": 1,
    "revisionNumber": 0,
    "name": "Revision 0",
    "parentRevisionNode": null,
    "nextRevisionNode": null,
    "prevRevisionNode": null,
    "childRevisionNodes": [
      {
          "$id": "2",
          "id": 2,
          "revisionNumber": 0,
          "name": "Node 1",
          "parentRevisionNode": {
              "$ref": "1"
          },
          "nextRevisionNode": null,
          "prevRevisionNode": null,
          "childRevisionNodes": [
            {
                "$id": "3",
                "id": 3,
                "revisionNumber": 0,
                "name": "Node 1.1",
                "parentRevisionNode": {
                    "$ref": "2"
                },
                "nextRevisionNode": null,
                "prevRevisionNode": null,
                "childRevisionNodes": null,
                "data": {
                    "$id": "4",
                    "id": 3,
                    "revisionNumber": 0,
                    "text": "Data 1.1",
                    "parentRevisionNode": {
                        "$ref": "3"
                    },
                    "nextRevisionNode": null
                }
            },
            {
                "$id": "5",
                "id": 4,
                "revisionNumber": 0,
                "name": "Node 1.2",
                "parentRevisionNode": {
                    "$ref": "2"
                },
                "nextRevisionNode": null,
                "prevRevisionNode": null,
                "childRevisionNodes": null,
                "data": {
                    "$id": "6",
                    "id": 4,
                    "revisionNumber": 0,
                    "text": "Data 1.2",
                    "parentRevisionNode": {
                        "$ref": "5"
                    },
                    "nextRevisionNode": null
                }
            }
          ],
          "data": {
              "$id": "7",
              "id": 2,
              "revisionNumber": 0,
              "text": "Data 1",
              "parentRevisionNode": {
                  "$ref": "2"
              },
              "nextRevisionNode": null
          }
      }
    ],
    "data": {
        "$id": "8",
        "id": 1,
        "revisionNumber": 0,
        "text": "Data 0",
        "parentRevisionNode": {
            "$ref": "1"
        },
      "nextRevisionNode": null
    }
}
```

I found a function that replaces the $id and $ref with the Object. Thats working fine.

Now i want the get that Object Tree back to the Server. But i get an error with circling references on JS Side. Then i thought i can do the same way back, transform the Object References with $id and $ref.

But Angulars $resource cuts out all the $ attributes...

Anyone a good Idea how to get Data back and forth from/to Server?

Thanks in advance

Greeetings

Ronny Gerndt

Comment: Which version of angular and angular-resource are you using?

Comment: AngularJS v1.2.16 for both